# Vincular datos de Paradox (.db)

Tags: base-de-datos

tengo una consulta, tengo que abrir bases de datos paradox (.db) veo que se puede desde access o excel importando datos externos y vinculando las tablas, pero en ninguno de los casos tengo la opción de paradox, me debe faltar un driver pero tampoco lo encuentro. Alquilen sabrá como poder abrir o poder vincular los datos de este tipo de base de datos? mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder utilizar la BD de Paradox desde Access primero debes de convertirla a Access. En Google puedes encontrar varios conversores 14 días trial y alguno free.

Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: en primer lugar muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Puede hacer que desde access me permita tener la opción de importar datos de parador pero al agregar las tablas me dice que el formato no es el correcto o que no encuentra la ruta del archivo. Debe tener que ver con el driver.  voy a ver si encuentro los conversores que me decis, porque debería tener que haber una forma más sencilla de abrir estos archivos. Gracias